# Can't fscanf all lines into Struct array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, scanf

I am trying to fscanf() into a struct array. I have followed the suggested resolution prior to making this post, but for some reason it doesn't seem like its reading all the data in the file. This is just the beginning of what I need complete, since later I have to sort the items in my struct.

```
#define LCOUNT 128  // Sizeof of single line
#define ROW_COUNT 2 // Number of lines in file

struct Hurricane {
    char Year[50];
    char Name[50];  
    char State[50];
};

int main() {
    
    struct Hurricane hurricane[ROW_COUNT]; // Declare hurricane of type Hurricane array
    
    // File operations
    FILE *fptr = fopen("hurricane.txt", "r");
    
    // Return error if file no bueno
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Failed to open file");
        return -1;
    }
    
    // Start of row
    int ROW;
    
    // Read comma as delimiter into Struct
    while(ROW != ROW_COUNT) {
        
            fscanf(fptr, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]\n", &hurricane[ROW].Year, &hurricane[ROW].Name, &hurricane[ROW].State);
            printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", hurricane[ROW].Year, hurricane[ROW].Name, hurricane[ROW].State);
            ROW++;
        
    }
        
    // Close file
    fclose(fptr);
    
    return 0;
}
```

And my files contents:

> 1960,Donna,FL-NC
>
> 1969,Camille,MS
>
> 1972,Agnes,FL

And then the output:

> 1960    Donna   FL-NC
>
> 1969
>
> -------------------------------- Process exited after 0.02288 seconds with return value 0 Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: ROW is not intialized, the behavior is undefined. ROW_COUNT is 2, you will read only 2 line initializing ROW with 0

Comment: You need to check the return value from `fscanf()`.  Always check the return value from your input functions.

Comment: "for some reason it doesn't seem like its reading" --> Save time, check the return value form `fscanf()` `if (fscanf(fptr, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]\n" != 3) fail();`

Comment: herboren, Why does code have unused `LCOUNT`?

Comment: I re-modified the code so many times, it didn't occur to me to remove unused stuff if I knew it wouldn't hurt the code. I leave it for reminders to myself of what it was used for. Supposed I should comment it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ROW_COUNT should be 3 and not 2
- ROW should be initialized like bruno mentions in comments: `int ROW = 0;`
- the fscanf call should look like this

  ```
  fscanf(fptr, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^\n]\n", hurricane[ROW].Year, hurricane[ROW].Name, hurricane[ROW].State);
  ```

If you search for `,%[^,]` as the last part of the string, then read to the next comma, but your line does not end with a comma. Therefore it's better to use e.g.`%[^\n]`.

Comment: Excellent, ty that worked. I updated the row and row count as well is the fscanf parameters and it worked flawlessly. Really the printf was just to confirm that it was obtaining the results, but I will be removing the print until later debugging. Now, its time to sort and output to a file. Thank you guys.